# Rodar varios videos

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

Possuo cerca de 8 sequencia de vídeos que precisam rodar conforme o usuário escolhe a opção (1 = Video_1, 2 = Video_2)

Exemplo:

"Digite a opção desejada"

"1 - Ligar Motor maquina 01"

"2 - Restabelecer conexão com o eixo Y"

Ai quando ele escolher a opção "1" o script vai abrir os videos referente a opção 1 (localizados dentro da pasta '/home/pi/desktop/v1/vX.mp4')

Porém quando eu uso

```
for x in range(1,8):
   file = 'Video_' + str(x)
   os.system('omxplayer --aspect-mode fill -o local /home/pi/video_{}.mp4'.format(file))
```

Ou ele só roda o primeiro video ou ele não roda nada

Alguém já passou por isso? Pode me dar uma ajuda?

Comment: E em que momento o usuário escolhe a opção? Como você verifica qual vídeo executar conforme a opção dele?

Comment: Tipo vai aparecer no terminal do rasp um "menu" com as opções, dai pra achar a sequencia de videos (falei errado na pergunta) ele vai achar na pasta "01" os videos que devem ser executados